# Hovering effect on image in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hover

***Before helping, I am aware CSS is much easier, but please do not give CSS solutions as I was told to only touch the .js file.***

I am not sure what is wrong here in my code as I've searched online and this is what I believe I should have in my code, however my image isn't having the opacity and duration effect at all that I intended it to have.

Here is part of the HTML that is involved with the javascript:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="myCols" class="container">
        <div class="col1">
            <img src="images/boxImage1.jpg" class="imageCS"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <img src="images/boxImage2.png" class="imageCS"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <img src="images/boxImage3.jpg" class="imageCS"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript that I have keyed in:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{


    $("imageCS").hover(function()

        //hover over opacity 30% at 0.5 sec
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.3"}, "0.5"); 
    ),

    function()
    (
        //hover out opacity 100% at 1 sec
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, "1"); 
    )




});
```

I am not sure what is wrong as the effect isn't even taking place.

Comment: `$(".imageCS")` - you need a dot for a class and # for id

Comment: @dusan jovanov

thanks for that input, however the hover over effect still isn't working for me.

Comment: This works for me : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".imageCS").hover(function(){
                $(this).animate({"opacity":0.3},500)
            },
            function(){
                $(this).animate({"opacity":1},500)
            });
        });
    </script>` ..... `<div id="myCols" class="container">
        <img src="Koala.jpg" class="imageCS">
    </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is missing in your element selection and you can use `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

```js
$('.imageCS').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','.2');
    
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="imageCS"/>
```

If you want to Use the `hover` see the following snippet:

```js
 $('.imageCS').hover(  
   function () {
     $(this).css('opacity','.2');
   }, 
   function () {
     $(this).css('opacity','1');
   }
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="imageCS"/>
```

***Calling $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ) is shorthand for:
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );***

Check Documentation [Here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: sorry afnan, but I have to use hover over and hover out as well for this case. DO i just replacethe mouseover with hover?

Also, I am not allowed to use CSS. Am I still suppose to use $(this).css?

Comment: @lala you were told to only touch the .js file so this has nothing to do with .css file. you can use it in your js file.